# Installation boot options not working

Tags: system-installation

I have downloaded Ubuntu 14.04, copies it to DVD disk and attempted to install. I can get as far as the install option GUI:

Boot menu screenshot:

[image]

This is where the problem arises. When I select 'Try Ubuntu', 'Install Ubuntu' or 'Check disk for defect' I just get a flashing cursor and after about 10 seconds PC starts to boot to Windows. I have an old Ubuntu 9.0* disk and this works ok.

Thank you very much if you can help.

System:

### System Information

```
Time of this report: 6/27/2014, 16:33:36
       Machine name: HOME-9D67C3B1A7
   Operating System: Windows XP Home Edition (5.1, Build 2600) Service Pack 3 (2600.xpsp_sp3_qfe.130704-0421)
           Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
System Manufacturer: Dell Inc.                
       System Model: Dell DM051                   
               BIOS: Phoenix ROM BIOS PLUS Version 1.10 A05
          Processor: Intel(R) Pentium(R) D  CPU 2.66GHz (2 CPUs)
             Memory: 3062MB RAM
          Page File: 963MB used, 3984MB available
        Windows Dir: C:\WINDOWS
    DirectX Version: DirectX 9.0c (4.09.0000.0904)
DX Setup Parameters: Not found
     DxDiag Version: 5.03.2600.5512 32bit Unicode
```

---

### DxDiag Notes

```
  DirectX Files Tab: No problems found.
      Display Tab 1: No problems found.
        Sound Tab 1: No problems found.
          Music Tab: No problems found.
          Input Tab: No problems found.
        Network Tab: No problems found.
```

---

### DirectX Debug Levels

```
Direct3D:    0/4 (n/a)
DirectDraw:  0/4 (retail)
DirectInput: 0/5 (n/a)
DirectMusic: 0/5 (n/a)
DirectPlay:  0/9 (retail)
DirectSound: 0/5 (retail)
DirectShow:  0/6 (retail)
```

---

### Display Devices

```
        Card name: NVIDIA GeForce4 MX 4000 (Microsoft Corporation)
     Manufacturer: NVIDIA
        Chip type: GeForce4 MX 4000
         DAC type: Integrated RAMDAC
       Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_0185&SUBSYS_00000000&REV_C1
   Display Memory: 128.0 MB
     Current Mode: 1920 x 1080 (32 bit) (60Hz)
          Monitor: Plug and Play Monitor
  Monitor Max Res: 1600,1200
      Driver Name: nv4_disp.dll
   Driver Version: 6.14.0010.5673 (English)
      DDI Version: 9 (or higher)
Driver Attributes: Final Retail
 Driver Date/Size: 4/14/2008 06:42:04, 4274816 bytes
      WHQL Logo'd: n/a
  WHQL Date Stamp: n/a
              VDD: n/a
         Mini VDD: nv4_mini.sys
    Mini VDD Date: 8/3/2004 23:29:56, 1897408 bytes
Device Identifier: {D7B71E3E-42C5-11CF-9975-0A2060C2CB35}
        Vendor ID: 0x10DE
        Device ID: 0x0185
        SubSys ID: 0x00000000
      Revision ID: 0x00C1
      Revision ID: 0x00C1
      Video Accel: 
 Deinterlace Caps: n/a
         Registry: OK
     DDraw Status: Enabled
       D3D Status: Enabled
       AGP Status: Not Available
DDraw Test Result: Not run
 D3D7 Test Result: Not run
 D3D8 Test Result: Not run
 D3D9 Test Result: Not run
```

---

### Sound Devices

```
            Description: SigmaTel Audio
 Default Sound Playback: Yes
 Default Voice Playback: Yes
            Hardware ID: HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_8384&DEV_7680&SUBSYS_102801AB&REV_1036
        Manufacturer ID: 1
             Product ID: 100
                   Type: WDM
            Driver Name: sthda.sys
         Driver Version: 5.10.4568.0000 (English)
      Driver Attributes: Final Retail
            WHQL Logo'd: n/a
          Date and Size: 6/14/2005 18:40:08, 180864 bytes
            Other Files: 
        Driver Provider: SigmaTel
         HW Accel Level: Full
              Cap Flags: 0x0
    Min/Max Sample Rate: 0, 0
Static/Strm HW Mix Bufs: 0, 0
 Static/Strm HW 3D Bufs: 0, 0
              HW Memory: 0
       Voice Management: No
 EAX(tm) 2.0 Listen/Src: No, No
   I3DL2(tm) Listen/Src: No, No
Sensaura(tm) ZoomFX(tm): No
               Registry: OK
      Sound Test Result: Not run
```

---

### Sound Capture Devices

```
            Description: SigmaTel Audio
  Default Sound Capture: Yes
  Default Voice Capture: Yes
            Driver Name: sthda.sys
         Driver Version: 5.10.4568.0000 (English)
      Driver Attributes: Final Retail
          Date and Size: 6/14/2005 18:40:08, 180864 bytes
              Cap Flags: 0x0
           Format Flags: 0x0
```

---

### DirectMusic

```
    DLS Path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\drivers\GM.DLS
 DLS Version: 1.00.0016.0002
Acceleration: n/a
       Ports: Microsoft Synthesizer, Software (Not Kernel Mode), Output, DLS, Internal, Default Port
              SigmaTel Audio, Software (Kernel Mode), Output, DLS, Internal
              Microsoft MIDI Mapper [Emulated], Hardware (Not Kernel Mode), Output, No DLS, Internal
              Microsoft GS Wavetable SW Synth [Emulated], Hardware (Not Kernel Mode), Output, No DLS, Internal
    Registry: OK
 Test Result: Not run
```

---

### DirectInput Devices

```
      Device Name: Mouse
         Attached: 1
    Controller ID: n/a
Vendor/Product ID: n/a
        FF Driver: n/a

      Device Name: Keyboard
         Attached: 1
    Controller ID: n/a
Vendor/Product ID: n/a
        FF Driver: n/a

Poll w/ Interrupt: No
         Registry: OK
```

---

Comment: are you using the 32 bit version of Ubuntu?

Comment: No its the 64 bit. "ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso" I'll try the 32 bit version. Thanks for replying.

Comment: No luck with the 32 bit version either. Same problems. Tks anyway.

Comment: I always had to use nomodeset to get my nVidia system to work. And until I installed the nVidia driver has to boot with nomodeset. Use f6 other options on screen and choose nomodeset. http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it  I also had to use nomodeset on first boot by editing grub menu.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not related but I had an issue with some Dell machines not playing nice with the latest Ubuntu and in one case was able to resolve the problem with a BIOS update. I see you are running A05 and I'm willing to guess that there is an updated BIOS available for your system.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, If you  are not confident enough that your answer is related then it would be better as a comment. You are able to post comments on other peoples questions/answers when you have enough [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation).